# Content Wider than Screen on Mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to solve the mobile usability error that says "Content wider than screen"
A video showing the same is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19hv0TrEG7utIG8gskm0c98VBdBhNoI6l/view?usp=sharing

Sample page: https://askanydifference.com/difference-between-state-and-federal-prison/

I have tried a number of CSS and layout fixes but this error never goes away.
Now I want to see if ads are causing this layout issue. I am using WordPress CMS.

To further complicate this, the horizontal scrollbar doesn't always show up. This means sometimes, the page doesn't have content wider than the screen issue.

Can someone please take a look and advise the direction in which I need to move further while diagnosing this issue.

Thanks

Comment: You should post related codes into your question, instead of adding an external link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because fix width of the container (text), by default containers are responsive. Remove fixed width and make width 100% or leave it there as it is.